# Allign label and TextArea in XML View

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a layout problem. I want to allineate the label and the text area into a form. I don't like my output:

[image]
 How can I do it?
There is a wrong definition of the text area?

My viwe is this, 
Where is the problem?

```
...
        <content>  
            <l:Grid
                defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
                hSpacing="2"
                width="auto">
                <l:content>
                  <f:Form id="FormNewNomDog"
                    minWidth="1024"
                    maxContainerCols="2"
                    editable="false"
                    class="isReadonly">
                    <f:layout>
                      <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                        labelSpanL="3"
                        labelSpanM="3"
                        emptySpanL="4"
                        emptySpanM="4"
                        columnsL="1"
                        columnsM="1" />
                    </f:layout>
                    <f:formContainers>
                      <f:FormContainer>
                        <f:formElements>

                          <f:FormElement label="Codice nome doganale">
                            <f:fields>
                              <TextArea xmlns="sap.m"
                                    id="idCodNomDog"
                                    value=""
                                    width=""
                                    enabled="true"
                                    valueState="None"
                                    rows="1"
                                    change=""
                                    liveChange="onChangeFormElement">
                                </TextArea>
                            </f:fields>
                          </f:FormElement>

                          <f:FormElement label="Bene o Servizio">
                            <f:fields>
                              <Switch state="false" customTextOn="Bene" customTextOff="Serv" id="idBenSer">
                                  <layoutData>
                                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                                  </layoutData>
                              </Switch>
                            </f:fields>
                          </f:FormElement>

                          <f:FormElement label="Presenza unita' supplementare">
                            <f:fields>
                              <Switch state="false" id="idPresUnSuppl" change="onChangePresUnSuppl">
                                  <layoutData>
                                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                                  </layoutData>
                              </Switch>

                            </f:fields>
                          </f:FormElement>

                          <f:FormElement label="Descrizione unita' supplementare">
                            <f:fields>
                              <TextArea xmlns="sap.m"
                                    id="idDescUnSuppl"
                                    value=""
                                    width=""
                                    enabled="false"
                                    valueState="None"
                                    rows="1"
                                    change=""
                                    liveChange="onChangeFormElement">
                                </TextArea>
                            </f:fields>
                          </f:FormElement>

                        </f:formElements>
                      </f:FormContainer>
                    </f:formContainers>
                  </f:Form>
                </l:content>
              </l:Grid>
        </content>



    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set `editable="true"` instead of `"false"`.