# Mixed editable and no-editable fields in a form

Tags: sapui5

I have "BIG" problem  with a form and its fields:
[image]

I want have a mixed content: editable and not editable field. If i set `editable="true"` the allign of the editable fields is correct, instead id I set `editable="false"` the allign of the not-editable fields is correct.

The code of the controller is:

```
this.byId("rowDetFormEditContainer").removeAllFormElements();
        for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
            var formEl = new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement();
            formEl.setLabel(cols[i]);


            //small edit (beni)
            else if((getActualOperationId()=="dettBeniPeriodo"||getActualOperationId()=="dettRettificheBeni")&&(cols[i]=='NOM_DOGANALE')){
                this.getView().setModel('bene','updateType');
                if(cols[i]=='NOM_DOGANALE'){
                    var codNomnclList=sap.ui.getCore().getModel('codNomnclList');
                    var field=new sap.m.Input({value : itemToEdit[Object.keys(itemToEdit)[i]]});
                    for(var k=0;k<codNomnclList.beni.length;k++){
                        field.addSuggestionItem(new sap.ui.core.Item().setKey(codNomnclList.beni[k]).setText(codNomnclList.beni[k]));
                        field.setShowSuggestion(true);
                    }
                    formEl.addField(field);

                }else{
                    formEl.addField(new sap.m.Text({text:itemToEdit[Object.keys(itemToEdit)[i]]}));
                }



            }else{
                formEl.addField(new sap.m.Text({text:itemToEdit[Object.keys(itemToEdit)[i]]}));
            }

            this.byId("rowDetFormEditContainer").addFormElement(formEl);

        }
```

and into XML View i write:

```
<Page id='pageRowDetailEdit' title="Modifica" showNavButton="true" navButtonPress="doBack">
        <content>
        <l:Grid
            defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12"
            hSpacing="2"
            width="auto">
            <l:content>
              <f:Form id="FormEdit"
                minWidth="1024"
                maxContainerCols="2"
                editable="false"
                class="isReadonly">
                <f:title>
                  <core:Title text="Modifica" />
                </f:title>
                <f:layout>
                  <f:ResponsiveGridLayout
                    labelSpanL="3"
                    labelSpanM="3"
                    emptySpanL="4"
                    emptySpanM="4"
                    columnsL="1"
                    columnsM="1" />
                </f:layout>
                 <f:formContainers>
                   <f:FormContainer id="rowDetFormEditContainer">

                  </f:FormContainer> 
                </f:formContainers> 
              </f:Form>
            </l:content>
          </l:Grid>

        </content>

        <footer>
          <Bar>
            <contentRight>
              <Button text="Accetta" press="onPressOnAccept" type="Accept" />
            </contentRight>
          </Bar>
        </footer>



    </Page>
```

Comment: this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24449758/allign-label-and-textarea-in-xml-view not resolve it

Comment: Have you done some extra CSS modifications? Normally it should just be aligned ok. Furthermore, your controller code is incorrect, it shows an `else if` without a preceding `if` statement

Comment: Yes, i cut the if block previous the else if.
I have not changed the CSS. Any Solutions?

Comment: I noticed, in the demokit samples, they added an extra "padding-top: 16px;" to the labels if the form is editable... but if you have a form with mixed editable elements, this may not work. Bottomline is, unfortunately you have to modify your CSS :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its the problem with the `Element` your using in `addField()`.

Next to this `NOM_DOGANALE` your using `input` element, else where your using `text`.

use `input` instead  `text` and use `setEditable(false)`. this should work.